# Multiple servlets in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to deploy an app to a local development google app engine server. I cannot seem to get multiple servlets to co-exist. Here is my web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Admin</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Main</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've tried adding wild cards, changing the order of servlets in the file, and a number of other things. No matter what, anytime I visit /admin (or /admin/) it shows the Main servlet as if I was visiting just /. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove the slash after /admin

```
<url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and had no luck. Basically I have tried /admin, /admin/, /admin/*, and none work for me. I even changed the name of the servlet in case I was conflicting with the GAE admin page, and nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping your `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` blocks together. Oh, and remove the slashes.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Admin</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Main</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```